# Using MSDeploy to a Windows 7 computer running default IIS

Tags: windows, iis, windows-7, msdeploy

My question is rather simple.

Has anybody here successfully used the publish function of Visual Studio 2010 to publish a web app to a **Windows 7 computer running the default IIS?**

I have struggled for who knows how long to try to get this working and am starting to wonder if it is at all possible!?!?

To test I have done things right, I whacked a Server 2008 VM up and following some articles, and managed to get the deploy working rather easily on the 2008 server.

So is there any thing special I need to do on a Windows 7 Ultimate machine? or am I wasting my time because it is not possible?

Comment: What does "running the default IIS" mean? Win7/sp1 uses IIS 7.5, the same bits as Win08/R2/SP1.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the blog post [Test your ASP.NET MVC or WebForms Application on IIS 7 in 30 seconds](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/04/22/test-you-asp-net-mvc-or-webforms-application-on-iis-7-in-30-seconds.aspx), which provides all the steps to get a VS 2010 web app running on IIS on Windows 7. You'll need to open your Windows 7 Firewall to HTTP traffic to browse the app from another computer, but that's covered in the blog post.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, will have a look when I get the chance. Tx